# Question about Error thrown in new Promise

Tags: javascript

```js
try {
    console.log(1)
    new Promise(() => {
        console.log(2)
        throw new Error('promise error')
    })
    console.log(3)
} catch(e) {
    console.log('hello error');
}
```

The log of this code is `1, 2, 3` which means the code in `new Promise` runs synchronously.

So why can't `try catch` catch `Error` thrown in synchronous code?

Comment: all errors in the promise constructor callback are handled and rejects the promise.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?  I'm not completely clear on the question...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2):

The `Promise` constructor catches the error and turns it into a rejected promise. You're unable to catch it for the same reason the second `try-catch` here doesn't catch any error:

```js
function tryFunc(f) {
  try{ f() } catch (e) {}
}

try {
   console.log(1);
   tryFunc(() => {
       console.log(2);
       throw new Error();
   });
   console.log(3);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('hello error');
}
```

Here you can observe that the error is converted into a rejected promise:

```js
console.log('Before new Promise()');

new Promise(() => {
    console.log('In new Promise()');
    throw new Error('i am an error');
}).catch((e) => console.error('Caught error:', e.message));

console.log('After new Promise()');
```

Answer (score 0):

Chain  a `catch()` to your Promise and you will see why your outer try/catch doesn't see the error thrown in the Promise constructor.

Promise constructor has it's own internal try/catch

```js
try {
    console.log(1)
    new Promise(() => {
        console.log(2)
        throw new Error('promise error')
    }).catch(({message})=> console.log(message));
    console.log(3)
} catch(e) {
    console.log('hello error');
}
```